# How to create ec2 instance using java lambda function?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am able to create an EC2 instance using Java from my local machine in Eclipse.
The issue that I am facing is I cannot find a way to create an EC2 instance using Java Lambda Function.
Can someone please help me?

The lambda function I am using:-

```
package com.ec2application.ec2application;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.CreateTagsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.Instance;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.RunInstancesRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.RunInstancesResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.StartInstancesRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.Tag;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class EC2UsingLambda implements RequestHandler<Object, String> 
{
    private static final AWSCredentials AWS_CREDENTIALS;

    static {
        // Your accesskey and secretkey
        AWS_CREDENTIALS = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                "myid",
                "key"
        );
    }


    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) 
    {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);

        // TODO: implement your handler
        // Set up the amazon ec2 client
        AmazonEC2 ec2Client = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(AWS_CREDENTIALS))
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .build();

        // Launch an Amazon EC2 Instance
        RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest().withImageId("ami-0080e4c5bc078760e")
                .withInstanceType("t2.micro") // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html
                .withMinCount(1)
                .withMaxCount(1)
                .withKeyName("priyajdm")
                .withNetworkInterfaces(new InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification()
                        .withAssociatePublicIpAddress(true)
                        .withDeviceIndex(0)
                        .withSubnetId("subnet-02ffd56c277")
                        .withGroups("sg-0e93be4d"));

        RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult = ec2Client.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);

        Instance instance = runInstancesResult.getReservation().getInstances().get(0);
        String instanceId = instance.getInstanceId();
        System.out.println("EC2 Instance Id: " + instanceId);

        // Setting up the tags for the instance
        CreateTagsRequest createTagsRequest = new CreateTagsRequest()
                .withResources(instance.getInstanceId())
                .withTags(new Tag("Name", "demo"));
        ec2Client.createTags(createTagsRequest);

        // Starting the Instance
        StartInstancesRequest startInstancesRequest = new StartInstancesRequest().withInstanceIds(instanceId);

        ec2Client.startInstances(startInstancesRequest);
        return "EC2 Instance created";
    }

}
```

This is the code I have used:-
This is the error I have got:-

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/priyj_kumar/workspace/EC2Application/src/main/java/com/ec2application/ec2application/EC2UsingLambda.java:[16,45] package com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/priyj_kumar/workspace/EC2Application/src/main/java/com/ec2application/ec2application/EC2UsingLambda.java:[17,45] package com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/priyj_kumar/workspace/EC2Application/src/main/java/com/ec2application/ec2application/EC2UsingLambda.java:[19,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class RequestHandler
[ERROR] /C:/Users/priyj_kumar/workspace/EC2Application/src/main/java/com/ec2application/ec2application/EC2UsingLambda.java:[32,47] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Context
  location: class com.ec2application.ec2application.EC2UsingLambda
[INFO] 4 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your AWS Lambda probably has not the permission to do so. Have a look here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-permissions.html.

Comment: I have tried the same with a simple hello world function and it worked successfully.

Comment: @Priyaj, have you tried to create an EC2 instance with Lambda yet? If so, what have you tried and what issues are you having?

Comment: no, i have just tried it with a simple lambda function returning Hello world. I have created ec2 instance with Python though.

Comment: Why do you believe running a `hello world function` would be the same as an action which requires a grant like `ec2:RunInstances`?

Comment: Please show us your Lambda function and tell us the error message you are receiving.

Comment: @SubOptimal I know there is a huge difference between both. I just said that I tried my first code in Java as a Hello world program and it did work and Creating an EC2 didn't.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I will share the code.

Comment: @SubOptimal I have shared the code please have a look

Comment: What have you already tried to solve this issue `package com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime does not exist`?.

Comment: @SubOptimal, i tried adding the relevant jar files and also changing the dependency in pom.xml but none worked out. Can please someone help me with this? I am stuck and out of options

Comment: Please try to be a bit more verbose about the steps you did. `adding the relevant jar` and `changing the dependency in pom.xml` is just to verbose to show what you did. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve how to provide useful information for someone to be able to reproduce/understand your problem. If it takes to much time to get the concrete problem, there are good chances no one will try to waste **his time** for **your problem**.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a Java API call that invokes a given service in a Lambda function. We have written an article that shows you how to create a Lambda function that invokes an AWS Service operation by using a given service client.

Then the Lambda function is used in AWS Steps to create a workflow. If you follow this document, you will see the pattern to successfully invoke AWS Service operation from code that can be wrapped in a Lambda function. See:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_serverless%20workflows

In your use case, you can use the EC2 Service Client within a Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've included the aws-lambda-java-core dependency

The [Lambda developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html) goes into the process in detail